# How do I tell VS Code how to refresh my compile_commands.json file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have a `c_cpp_properties.json` file like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "compileCommands": "build/compile_commands.json"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I also have a script in my project that generates `build/compile_commands.json`. Let's call it `gen-compile-commands.sh`.

How do I configure VS Code to call this script after any file in my project tree is created, destroyed or modified, so that it is always up-to-date?

Comment: If you can use an extension then.. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave